# SonarQube: Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "true"

Tags: java, refactoring, sonarqube

Hola Comunidad estoy recibiendo por SonarQube un bug que no he podido zafar en especifico en una linea de un if la cual me dice que cambie el código para que no siempre sea verdadero, le he dado vueltas pero no logro salir de allí.

El error es el siguiente:

```
Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to “true”
```

Y la función en cuestión es esta:

```
    public static boolean validarRut(String rut) {

    boolean validacion = false;
    try {
        rut =  rut.toUpperCase();
        rut = rut.replace(".", "");
        rut = rut.replace("-", "");
        int rutAux = Integer.parseInt(rut.substring(0, rut.length() - 1));

        char dv = rut.charAt(rut.length() - 1);

        int m = 0, s = 1;
        for (; rutAux != 0; rutAux /= 10) {
            s = (s + rutAux % 10 * (9 - m++ % 6)) % 11;
        }
        if (dv == (char) (s != 0 ? s + 47 : 75)) {
            validacion = true;
        }

    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return validacion;
}
```

ahora la linea especifica del bug que reclama SonarQube es esta:

```
if (dv == (char) (s != 0 ? s + 47 : 75)) {
        validacion = true;
    }
```

Sonar marca la siguiente parte del codigo `s != 0 ?`
con el siguiente error: `Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to “true”`

Agradecería la ayuda y explicación ya me he dado varias vueltas jeje Saludos y gracias a todos

Comment: ¿Podrías transcribir el error completo a la pregunta?

Comment: @Mateo realice el cambio a la pregunta, gracias.

Comment: ¿Enserio no aporta más que el título?

Comment: es lo único que veo en sonar cuando marco el bug

Comment: Me pregunto por qué usas la instrucción `rut.substring(0, rut.length() - 1)` si no produce ningún string diferente al original. El primer parámetro es el índice de inicio y el segundo el índice de fin.

Answer (score 0):

Por algún motivo, `s != 0` siempre es verdadero. Ya que esto sucede, podrías reemplazar la expresión `s != 0 ? s + 47 : 75` por `s + 47` y no deberías tener ese error.